# Can I use two different versions of web config files in my application in .net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, google-api-dotnet-client

- I'm using Visual Studio 2008 which will support only .net 3.5
- I want to use .net 4.0 for one aspx page by creating sub
  folder will it support, if main `web.config` file of .net 3.5 and sub
  folder web.config file is .net 4.0.

The reason for this is so that I can to use [Google .net client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) with the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) in my application.  The [Google .net Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) does not support the .net 3.5 framework.

Comment: Check This http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11034/Working-with-more-than-one-Web-config-file

Comment: You could just not use the client library and hard code all the calls to the API its not that hard I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

hello i have not tried this but you can give a try.

1. add web.config (.net 3.5) to to root directory
2. create a vertual directory of folder of which you want to have web.config .net 4.0 (google analytics folder)
3. add a web.config (.net 4.0) in that vertual directory(google analytics).
4. in root directory web.config (.net 3.5) `allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"` do this.

and tell it works or not